# Utilize entire viewport of ePub for interactivity

Tags: html, css, epub

I am working on an ePub3 and I created an interactive document that requires the full page to really look how it should. Unfortunately when I compile it with Readium to test the functionality in the ePub it shrinks it to one half of the viewport and leaves the other half empty (because it is, after all, a book).

I googled around and messed with the CSS and DOM and I cannot figure out how to remove that extra, unused page and make the one page with the interactive app take up the entire viewport.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? I know it might be pushing the standards of the ePub, but this app is a huge part of the ePub.

I appreciate any advice that can be given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reader-specific display function (not an ePub3 function), so you won't be able to control it. It is similar to what happens on most tablets if you turn them to read in landscape mode... The thing is, many readers don't read in this mode but some do, and you wouldn't want to take that ability to choose away from them.

If you are doing this in a reflowable book, I would suggest having the App be on it's own fixed layout XHTML page so that it is full-screen (on tablets) at least. You can do this by creating the new XHTML page and putting a link to it.

The best visual solution I can see in Readium isn't really a solution, but you should just go to "settings" and read in single page mode and possibly have a tooltip recommending that to readers when they get to the app.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was tearing my hair out at this. It's nice to have some confirmation and some other options -- I really appreciate this, Alex!